# Can anybody help a newbie in C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am currently learning C# Console Application. I have a basic and maybe stupid question. I am trying to create a console application where if the user input a number, it will execute different commands. For example, if the user input "2", then it must start mspaint.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input your number: ");

       // if the number input = 2 (for example)
       // {
       //     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mspaint");
       // }
    }
}
```

Also, I have googled the solve to my problem, but did not manage to find an answer. Another little question would be:
How to execute the command based on what the number input is? For example if the number input is 3, then start word. if the number input is 2, then start paint, if the number input is 4, then start ie.
Also some code would help me a lot. Thank you :)

Comment: Take a look at these as a starting point: [`Console.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-3.1), [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch), and if you actually need to do maths, etc. with a number, [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) (this is `int`, but it exists for all the number types, and for some other types).

Comment: When you're working in an object oriented language, one of the best things to do is to read the documentation and see what's available. For example, you already know you need to use `Console` and `Diagnostics.Process` so head over to msdn and see what other methods, properties, and events these classes offer. Most likely they have something you need. If they don't, then start searching and asking. You'll be amazed how this will change your productivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello this could help.

```
        string choice;
        Console.WriteLine("Whats your choice?");
        choice = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (choice)
        {
            case "1":
                Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
                break;
            case "2":
                Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works :) It is exactly what I was looking for!